# USB Headset only working on the right side

Tags: arch-linux, audio

I connected my Logitech H390 USB Headset to my Arch Linux system and it only sounds on the right side of the headset. This is weird because I changed the headset for a new one and also connected it to a Windows system and it worked properly. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which Logitech headset ?

Comment: @Kiwy H390, now edited the question.

Comment: on Logitech site, it clearly states that it's supported on  Windows® or macOS or Chrome OS™

Comment: It is weird because one week ago the headset worked well.

Comment: I didn't say it won't work on linux just saying it's not officially supported, the problem you're having is probably solvable but I have absolutely no idea

Comment: I just had the same issue - I somehow decreased the volume on the left channel to 0 on my USB headphones. I couldn't see it in PulseAudio mixer but alsamixer showed exactly what was going on. So - `alsamixer` command in terminal, F6 to pick the headphones, choose Output with arrows, then for examle `6` to set both channels at 60% (`?` to show help)